# Vue: default value for prop function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Is there any way to set default function for prop with function type?

```
props: {
    clickFunction: {
        type: 'Function'
        default: ????
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't there be?  Did you try it?

Comment: I tried various things, but nothing works and there is no documentation about that.

Comment: My example works. What specifically isn't working as expected for you?

Comment: All other props support the default property, so it is an entirely safe assumption that a function would too.  I've done this to set an empty function as the default so that if it doesn't get passed in, the empty function does which will have no effect, and obviates the need to perform a conditional test for the function (I once wrote a jsperf proving that the default/empty function approach was faster).  Long story short if whatever you tried didn't work, then the problem was elsewhere.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes:

```js
Vue.component('foo', {
  template: '<div>{{ num }}</div>',
  props: {
    func: {
      type: Function,
      default: () => 1,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return { 
      num: this.func()
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <foo></foo>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried a bit different variants, but this one works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: To provide a method as a default function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57313153/use-current-vue-components-method-as-default-prop-value

Answer (score 28):

I'd say, always provide a default value that matched the type you specified: makes things much more easier to reason about. Here, what you are looking for would be a noop function (a.k.a. a function that does nothing):

```
props: {
  clickFunction: {
    type: Function
    default: () => {}
  }
}
```

You can then use `this.clickFunction()` in your code without checking it defensively first: it is *always* a function. Be sure you don't get mixed up with the default value for an `Object` prop, that would be an empty object:

```
props: {
  someObject: {
    type: Object
    default: () => ({})
  }
}
```

In Vue, `Object` and `Array` props must have their default value returned by a function to ensure they are distinct for every instance of the component (which does not seem to be required for `Function` props, but docs indeed aren't crystal clear about this).

Answer (score 4):

This way should work with Vue 2.0

```
props: {
    clickFunction: {
        type: 'Function'
        default(){
          return () => true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

I think this is not the right approach. VUE do not work that way. Why do want to pass reference to function as props? Component can emit its own event that parent can catch.

Here you have available props types:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

And here you can read about cutom events:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names

**Edit**
Yeah, my answer is not correct and does not answer the question.
Straight answer: yes, there are some any ways to set default function for prop with function type (look other answers).

Patterns and use-cases are off-topic so I end here (however, someone mentioned an interesting thing in response to my answer).

Comment: passing a function as a props to child components is a common pattern to pass value from child to parent in SPA frameworks. It's called "lifting state up callback" in React.JS https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html . VueJS also use this pattern.

Comment: `emit` is also a fine answer, if applicable. I am surprised by the amt of downvotes!

Comment: @BadDobby No - Vue doesn't use functions as props to lift state up - it uses the $emit, like Marcin is saying.