# Use current vue component's method as default prop value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am going to pass function as property to Vue component. Let it be function has to be invoked by `@click`. But for some reasons I want to keep default behaviour for the component. The default behaviour is not so easy as I want and I'm going to use `method` as default function. Because the default behaviour requires data from component's state (props, data, other methods, whatever).

Is there a way to do?

I've attached the example. Expected behaviour:

Button `works fine` should produce alert `You are welcome!`
Button `nope` should produce alert `You are welcome as well!` but does nothing.

```js
Vue.component('welcome-component', {
  template: '#welcome-component',
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    action: {
      type: Function,
      required: false,
      default: () => { this.innerMethod() },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    innerMethod() {
      alert("You are welcome as well!");
    }
  }
});


var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    externalMethod() {
      alert("You are welcome!");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  margin: 20px;
}

.holder > button {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <welcome-component name="works fine" :action="externalMethod"></welcome-component>
  <welcome-component name="nope"></welcome-component>
</div>


<script id='welcome-component' type='x-template'>
  <div class="holder">
    <button @click="action">{{ name }}</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: `default: () => {` How is it possible to reference `this` inside of an arrow function that is not within the scope? Or is it magically in scope in the Vue compiler? Or am i missing something?

Comment: @JamesHarrington exactly. This was *the question*.

Comment: Ah @MartenCatcher thanks for the clarification. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works but it's a total bag of spanners:

```js
action: {
  required: false,
  default () { 
    return () => this.innerMethod();
  },
},
```

I've had to remove the `type: Function`. Usually when `default` is a function it will be invoked to return the appropriate default value. However, if the prop has `type: Function` it'll just treat the function as the default. In this case that's problematic because we lose the `this` binding.

The internal arrow function is required to get around the problem that the methods aren't available when the `default` function is called.

If possible I would suggest giving up on using a `default` and instead just apply the 'default' when it needs to be invoked. So rather than calling `action` directly in the `click` handler, instead call a method called `invokeAction` that looks something like this:

```js
invokeAction () {
  if (this.action) {
    this.action();
  } else {
    this.innerMethod();
  }
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you. But I think I have to change the logic of my application to make it more standard.

Answer (score 7):

From vue docs:

`"Note that props are validated before a component instance is created, so instance properties (e.g. data, computed, etc) will not be available inside default or validator functions."` (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

Referencing the `innerMethod` is therefore one of the cases where the components function is not yet available.

Idea: If it is crucial for you to have this kind of functionality you could check within a later lifecycle hook (like created, mounted etc.) whether the type of `action` is `function`. If it's not a function (meaning not passed via prop), assign the innerMethod manually.